# Azure Blob storage trigger function using Docker

Tags: python, azure, docker

I am making a pipeline using Python and I found that Azure's default container does not support libsndfile library. So I am trying to use docker so that I can make a container which supports libsndfile library. However, I have not used docker so I need a help.

The function app that I made is blob storage triggered function app.

upload to blob storage (blob triggered) -> Processing (function app) -> copy to another blob storage (output)

The questions are

1. Is it possible to make a blob storage function app using docker?
2. If it is possible, can you give me some hints how to use docker?

Comment: Does the below answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

*In a case where when your functions require a specific language version or have a specific dependency or configuration that isn't provided by the built-in image, you typically use a custom image. Here, you can create and deploy your code to Azure Functions as a custom Docker container using a [Linux base image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp).*

**In summary**, you can create Azure Function App using Docker image using Azure LCI like below:

```
az functionapp create --name <app_name> --storage-account <storage_name> --resource-group AzureFunctionsContainers-rg --plan myPremiumPlan --runtime <functions runtime stack> --deployment-container-image-name <docker_id>/azurefunctionsimage:v1.0.0
```

Do check out the above link for detailed step by step tutorial and you are good to go! *It also shows you how to create output bindings.*